# When box is checked make a drop down readonly or uneditable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a drop down box in ruby on rails that allows a date to be entered. And there is a box beside it to indicate that no date will be entered.

When this box is ticked it changes the default value of the date to nil. However the user can still enter a date on the drop down boxes.

When the box is ticked I want the drop down to be readonly or uneditable how can I do this?

EDIT

```
function BlankOutStartDates() { 
if     (document.getElementById("service_unknown_start_date").checked == true) 
{ 
 document.getElementById("service_start_date_1i").selectedIndex = 0;     
 document.getElementById("service_start_date_2i").selectedIndex = 0;
 document.getElementById("service_start_date_3i").selectedIndex = 0; 
} 
}
```

I want to add the addition javascript to make the drop down box read only if the box is ticket

Comment: hey, which rails version are you using and do you have experience with javascript? i'd be happy to help you out, but i need to know how detailed i have to explain this.

Comment: Rails 3.0.3

Little bit of experience with javascript but not much

Currently I have it setting the values of the dates to the first element in drop down box

EDIT

Added the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually do this in jQuery. Suppose your checkbox has class "no-date", and your select boxes all of the class "date-select". Then you could do this:

```
jQuery(".no-date").change(function(){
   //Check if the box is checked
   if(this.is(':checked')){
      jQuery(".date-select").attr("disabled", "true");
   } else {
      jQuery(".date-select").removeAttr("disabled");
   }
});
```

You'll want to double check "this.is(':checked')" is correct, but I think that will work.

This uses the "disabled" parameter of select tags: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp